# What am I supposed to learn from my textbook saying 无论来自很有名的大学 is faulty wording?

Tags: grammar

> 大企业招聘主要看实力，没有实力的话，无论来自**很**有名的大学，人家也不要你。

This is considered a 病句 in the HSK6 Standard Course textbook page 30 ([photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo1PX.jpg)).  The explanation is:

> 带关联词的固定搭配误用。“无论/不管……多/多么……”是固定格式，“多么”表示任何一种程度。“无论”分句应改为“无论来自**多么**有名的大学”。

I'm unsure if this counts as "objectively wrong" or just "could be written better".  I'm also unsure as to what the take-home message of this is.

**Question**: What am I supposed to learn from my textbook saying 无论来自很有名的大学 is faulty wording?

Comment: It is "objectively wrong"

Answer (score 2):

To fix the sentence, you can simply replace 无论 with 就算(even if).

or write [无论(doesn't matter)] 来自[哪一间 (whichever)]很有名的大学

The word 无论 always followed by a question word like 'which', 'when', 'where', 'who', 'how', or 'A or B'.

It is objectively wrong to not include one after 无论

Answer (score 1):

**无论 .... 多/再 - no matter how**

- 无论来自**多/再**有名的大学... - no matter how famous the university you graduated from....
- 无论你多/再努力... - no matter how hard you try...
- 无论你多/再聰明... - no matter how smart you are...

Answer (score 0):

大企业招聘主要看实力，
(When) big companies are recruiting they mainly look for strength,  (they want body-builders??)
没有实力的话，
if you are not strong,
无论来自多有名的大学,人家也不要你.
(it) doesn't matter how famous a university you graduated from, they won't want you.

They are just saying "很" doesn't go with "无论"

Comment: 多 works because it means "how" in the phrase